# Analysis of Wine Quality dataset

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, classification, pca, multiclass-classification

I have a Dataset which explains the quality of wines based on the factors like acid contents, density, pH, etc. I am attaching the link which will show you the Wine Quality datset. According to the dataset we need to use the Multi Class Classification Algorithm to Analyze this dataset using Training and test data. Please correct me if I am wrong?

Wine_Quality.csv Dataset

https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/wine-quality/

Also I have used Principal Component Analysis Algorithm to work with this dataset. Below is the code I have used :-

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Sun Aug 26 14:14:44 2018

@author: 1022316
"""

# Wine Quality testing
#Multiclass classification - PCA

#importing the libraries
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

#importing the Dataset
dataset = pd.read_csv('C:\Machine learning\winequality-red_1.csv')
X = dataset.iloc[:, 0:11].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, 11].values

# Splitting the dataset into the Training set and Test set
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.25, random_state = 0)

# Feature Scaling
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc = StandardScaler()
X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = sc.transform(X_test)

#Applying the PCA
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
pca = PCA(n_components = 2 )
X_train = pca.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = pca.fit_transform(X_test)
explained_variance = pca.explained_variance_ratio_

# Fitting Logistic Regression to the Training set
#from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
#classifier = DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth = 2).fit(X_train, y_train)
#y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)

#classifier = LogisticRegression(random_state = 0)
#classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)

#Fiiting the Logistic Regression model to the training set
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
classifier = LogisticRegression(random_state = 0)
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)


#Predicting thr Test set results
y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)


# Making the Confusion Matrix
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
cm = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)
```

Please let me know if I am using the correct algorithm of this dataset. Also, as I can see we have 9 classes in which this dataset will be divided. Please also let me know how will I visualize and plot the data accordingly in different classes.

Comment: Just by scanning quickly over the dataset: It seems that the classes are extremely imbalanced, with a lot of wines being of "average" quality (around 5), and very little data on outliers. Make sure to respect something like that in your prediction! Also, try narrowing your question to a *specific* problem, and not asking for multiple things at once. That increases the chance of something helpful for both you and the community.

Comment: To echo what @dennlinger said: the question is a bit too broad as it stands to be a good fit for this site. One comment on the machine-learning aspect: don't re-fit your PCA on your test data! (in `X_test = pca.fit_transform(X_test)`). Instead, apply the transformation from your training data to your test data.

Comment: Hi All, Could you please elaborate in more details about the query and the answer which you have explained.

Comment: Also please let me know how and where I can post such type of questions and queries?

Answer (score 1):

> According to the dataset we need to use the Multi Class Classification Algorithm to Analyze this dataset using Training and test data. Please correct me if I am wrong?

Correct.

> Please let me know if I am using the correct algorithm of this dataset.

Yes. But a more systematic way to apply them would be: PCA is used first to visually explore the separability of classes and the relative informativeness of its components (you are using the first two). Then, logistic regression is applied in both the original high-dimensional and the PCA low-dimensional feature space.

```
#importing the libraries
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import  seaborn as sns

#importing the Dataset
dataset = pd.read_csv('winequality-red.csv', sep=';') # https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/wine-quality/winequality-red.csv
sns.countplot(dataset['quality'])
```

[image: observation: 6 classes and high class imbalance]

observation: 6 classes and high class imbalance (6 is perhaps because we are using different datasets in the page you shared).

> Also, as I can see we have 9 classes in which this dataset will be divided. Please also let me know how will I visualize and plot the data accordingly in different classes.

```
# Feature Scaling
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc = StandardScaler()
X = sc.fit_transform(X)

#Applying the PCA
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,6))
pca = PCA()
pca_all = pca.fit_transform(X)
pca1 = pca_all[:, 0]
pca2 = pca_all[:, 1]

fig.add_subplot(1,2,1)
plt.bar(np.arange(pca.n_components_), 100*pca.explained_variance_ratio_)
plt.title('Relative information content of PCA components')
plt.xlabel("PCA component number")
plt.ylabel("PCA component variance % ")

fig.add_subplot(1,2,2)
plt.scatter(pca1, pca2, c=y, marker='x', cmap='jet')
plt.title('Class distributions')
plt.xlabel("PCA Component 1")
plt.ylabel("PCA Component 2")
```

[image]

There are many metrics for quantifying multi-class classification performance. Using [accuracy](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html):

```
# Splitting the dataset into the Training set and Test set
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

#Fiiting the Logistic Regression model to the training set
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

classifier = LogisticRegression(random_state = 0)

# PCA 2D space
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(pd.DataFrame(data=pca_all).iloc[:,0:2], y, test_size = 0.25, random_state = 0)
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)
accuracy_pca_2d = accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)

# PCA 3D space
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(pd.DataFrame(data=pca_all).iloc[:,0:3], y, test_size = 0.25, random_state = 0)
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)
accuracy_pca_3d = accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)

# PCA 2D space
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.25, random_state = 0)
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)
accuracy_original = accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)

plt.figure()
sns.barplot(x=['pca 2D space', 'pca 3D space', 'original space'], y=[accuracy_pca_2d, accuracy_pca_3d, accuracy_original])
plt.ylabel('accuracy')
```

[image]

which shows doing the classification in the reduced PCA 2D space has a negative effect; at least, according to this measure and setup.

To visualize the confusion matrix, [this](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_confusion_matrix.html) can be used. Applying for the original space case:

[image]